# May I schect a chicken with a water jet?

Tags: halacha, water, slaughter-shochet-shecht

Water jet blades are used industrially to cut steel and if care is not taken can cut through flesh with better precision and in far less time than a steel blade.

Could this effect be exploited to schect a chicken?

Comment: Probably not, for example because you can't check the blade before *shechitah*.

Comment: @The that shouldn't be an issue if you know there are no nicks. There are a thousand other issues of course

Comment: One potential issue is that the material must be separate from it's source. For example a finger with a long fingernail could not be used as the nail would not be separate from the source. Not sure water coming from the ground through the ground is considered separate from its source. Another issue could be regarding whether water is considered smooth. Glass for example is invalid Bc while it can be sharp it isn't smooth.

Comment: Dear Dude: the water could be recirculated in a tank, recycled either by distillation or electrolysis, thus no need to come to the ground. Does that help?